# Two of my panels connect together when adding to the third panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was trying to add two panels in which each has their own components onto another panel, but when the program executes the two panels just amalgamate with each other. Please check out my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

/*
 * 2 Labels for withdraw/deposit.
* 2 Textfields for entering withdrawal/deposit amount.
* 1 Label for balance, 1 non-editable textfield for balance.
* Event listener on the calculate button.
* Action performed: balance minors withdrawal plus deposit
*/

/ **
* This class manages the input numbers. User will input withdrawal/deposit amount
* and the program will display the balacne after transfers.
* @author Administrator
*
*/

public class DataPanel extends JPanel {

public final int TEXTFIELD_LENGTH = 10;
public final int LAYOUT_VGAP = 25;
public final int LAYOUT_HGAP = 15;


/**
 * Constructor sets layout, creates labels/fields.
 */

public JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
public JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
public JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

    //Create necessary fields and labels
    JLabel withdrawalLabel = new JLabel("Withdrawal: ");
    JLabel depositLabel = new JLabel("deposit: ");
    JTextField withdrawalText = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_LENGTH);
    JTextField depositText = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_LENGTH);

    JLabel balanceLabel = new JLabel("Balance: ");
    JTextField balanceTextField = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_LENGTH);

    JLabel totalSavingLabel = new JLabel("Recently You Saved: ");
    JTextField totalSavingTextField = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_LENGTH);

    JLabel totalSpentLabel = new JLabel("Recently You Spent: ");
    JTextField totalSpentTextField = new JTextField(TEXTFIELD_LENGTH);

    //set some textfields non editable.


    //set layout, 3 rows + 2 columns.

    public DataPanel()
    {   
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        buildPane1();

        buildPane2();

        buildPane();

        add(pane);


    //add components to panel DataPanel.

}

    public void buildPane()
    {
        pane.add(pane1);
        pane.add(pane2);
    }

    public void buildPane1()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.PINK, 2, true));

        balanceTextField.setEditable(false);    

        pane1.add(withdrawalLabel);
        pane1.add(withdrawalText);
        pane1.add(depositLabel);
        pane1.add(depositText);
        pane1.add(balanceLabel);
        pane1.add(balanceTextField);
    }

    public void buildPane2()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2, true));

        totalSavingTextField.setEditable(false);
        totalSpentTextField.setEditable(false);

        pane2.add(totalSavingLabel);
        pane2.add(totalSavingTextField);
        pane2.add(totalSpentLabel);
        pane2.add(totalSpentTextField);

    }
}
```

JFrame class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
public final int WIDTH = 1000;
public final int HEIGHT = 800;

public DataPanel dataPane;
public InfoPanel infoPane;
public Menu menu;

public JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

//tab #1
public JPanel spendingPane;

//tab #2
public JPanel personalPane;

//tab #3
public JPanel socialPane;

//tab #4
public JPanel chatPane;



/**
 * Constructor. 
 */
public MainFrame()
{
    setTitle("Personal Banking");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    buildMenu();
    buildPanel();

    add(tabbedPane);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * This methods builds all the components.
 */

private void buildPanel()
{
    //build main panel (Spending  panel).
    dataPane = new DataPanel();



    //add numbers panel to the tabbed panel.
    tabbedPane.addTab("Numbers", dataPane);

    //build personal information panel.
    infoPane = new InfoPanel();
    personalPane = new JPanel();
    personalPane.add(infoPane);

    //add personal information panel to the tabbed panel.
    tabbedPane.addTab("Personal", personalPane);


}

/**
 * This function builds menu bar and menu items.
 */
private void buildMenu()
{
    menu = new Menu();
    setJMenuBar(menu.mainMenuBar);
}



public static void main(String args[])
{
    new MainFrame();
}
}
```

I have tried several methods, but they didn't actually work.

***Well apparently I pasted the first class twice. Now I fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Both panels are been added correctly (as near as I can tell), but you're applying the layout and border to the parent panel, not sure if that's what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: can you add a main method that will show the actual output when run?

Comment: Are you able to provide some idea of what it's suppose to do/look like?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply. MadProgrammer - I was trying to make the two panels look distinguished on that one panel, like, 3 rows and 2 columns on the left component, and 2 rows and 2 panels on the right component. Nikhil - Yes I will edit my post.

Comment: Tip:  Add an `@` before the name to ensure that the person is *notified* of a new comment.  Using the prefix, only one person can be notified per comment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Check the previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example (and a little change to the background color of each pane), you can see that they are been added

[image: Example]

However, this...

```
public void buildPane1()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.PINK, 2, true));
```

and this...

```
public void buildPane2()
{
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2, true));
```

look very suspicious, as they are been applied to the `DataPanel` and not (as I suspect you want) to the individual panels...

So changing them to look more like...

```
public void buildPane1() {

    pane1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    pane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.PINK, 2, true));

//...

public void buildPane2() {
    pane2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    pane2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2, true));
```

Gives me...

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand! What I originally did was to set the layout for the DataPanel, not for the individual panels that I wanted. It makes sense now!! ;)